# Gravity Forms REST API : Paging not working

Tags: php, wordpress, gravity-forms-plugin

I want to use Gravity Forms in WordPress through their V2 REST API. Basic Function is working, but their default number of entries returned is 10. They say they support setting another page size for the number of entries, but I can't seem to get it to work. Specifying it on the URL using "?paging[page_size]=20" results in an invalid request. Unfortunately, I am using a shared system and don't have access to the Gravity IDs in order to get support.

The following PHP code also seems to ignore the setting:

```
$jsonRequest = array( 'form_ids' => array("Sailing School Registration"), 'page_size' => '20' );

//Send request
$response = wp_remote_request( $full_url,
    array('method'  => 'GET',
      'body'    => json_encode( $jsonRequest ),
      'headers' => array('Content-type' => 'application/json')
    )
);
```